# Javascript: calling firebase function from client side is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to call firebase functions from client side but I'm getting error that firebase.functions is not a function

> main.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: firebase.functions is not a function

here is main.html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body  >

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
</div>
  
 
 

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.2/firebase-functions.js"></script>

<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script type="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "41414414I",
    authDomain: "414444.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://414144.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "414-c4cc",
    storageBucket: "4144-cc4cc.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "414542",
    appId: "1:41:web:31415425",
    measurementId: "G-542g542"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
  // Initialize Cloud Functions through Firebase
    var functions = firebase.functions();
</script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional

</script>

 
<script src="main.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

here is my main.js file

```js
 
random()
function random(){


var randomNumber = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('randomNumber');
randomNumber({text: messageText}).then(function(result) {
  // Read result of the Cloud Function.
  var sanitizedMessage = result.data.text;
  console.log(sanitizedMessage)

}).catch(function(error) {
  // Getting the Error details.
  var code = error.code;
  var message = error.message;
  var details = error.details;

  console.log(message)
  // ...
})

}
```

how can I fix the error and call firebase function from the client side?

After implementing Doug's answer it displayed

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete code sample that reproduces the problem.  We need to be able to see your script include for main.js in relation to the firebase scripts.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone can simply copy it and reproduce - right now, we can't see how man.js is included into your main.html along with firebase.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have updated the html file too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Firebase script includes are incorrect and out of order:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.2/firebase-functions.js"></script>

<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
```

Please review the instructions in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#from-the-cdn).  Firstly, don't include firebase.js.  Secondly, put them in the correct order, with firebase-app listed first.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.2/firebase-functions.js"</script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.2/firebase-analytics.js"</script>
```

Comment: Ok now its show this error  Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: If you have a new problem, please put some effort into debugging it, then post a new question with your code and details.  Stack Overflow is designed to deal with one problem at a time.